# Showing $y''' + y'^2 = 0$ with $y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = 1$, $y''(0) = 0$ is asymptotic to $x$ rigorously

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Considering the ODE problem given by $$y''' + y'^2 = 0$$ with $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$ and $y''(0) = 0$. Using Mathematica, it seems that numerically, the solution satisfies $y(x) \sim x$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. Without using a power series expansion, is there anyway to rigorously show this?

For reference numerically solving the above ODE in Mathematica results in the following picture.

[image: mathematica output]

Comment: Since $y$ is continuously differentiable, we have $$y(x) \underset{x\to 0}= y(0) + y'(0)x +o(x) \underset{x\to 0}= x +o(x) \underset{x\to 0}\approx x $$

Comment: Another way to see this: $y\sim x$ means $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{y}{x} = 1$. We have $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{y(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{y(x)-y(0)}{x} \equiv y'(0) = 1$ since $y(0) = 0$ and by the definition of the derivative.

Comment: It seems to me that based on the initial conditions you can prove that $y(x)=x$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @CTNT $y=x$ is not a solution to the ODE. If so $y'''=0$ and $y'=1$ so $y''' + (y')^2 = 1 \not= 0$.

Comment: @Winther Sorry my mistake. I miscalculated something in the error system.